# WSO2 EMM Store - Error 500 while trying to download an app

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've successfully installed WSO2 EMM on a linux server and I've tried to manage apps.
I've added one app in order to make some tests using the publisher an everything seems to be OK.
I log on the store, I can see my app, but when I click on it I got an "Error 500"

Checking the log I got the following :

```
ERROR {org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager} -  org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag#66) (/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag#55)
org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag#66) (/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag#55)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.exec(WebAppManager.java:587)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:507)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doGet(JaggeryServlet.java:24)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:748)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:486)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:338)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:613)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
    at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.authenticator.framework.WebappAuthenticationValve.invoke(WebappAuthenticationValve.java:43)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1074)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag#66) (/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag#55)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callName(OptRuntime.java:63)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0._c_anonymous_1(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag:55)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0.call(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0._c_script_0(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag:3)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0.call(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0.call(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.controllers.routers.c0.exec(/store/controllers/routers/assets.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.exceptions.ScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag#66)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:571)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.executeScript(WebAppManager.java:308)
    at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.include(WebAppManager.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.NullPointerException (/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag#66)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.extensions.assets.mobileapp.pages.c1._c_anonymous_1(/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag:66)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.extensions.assets.mobileapp.pages.c1.call(/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.c1._c_anonymous_70(/store/modules/store.js:1145)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.c1.call(/store/modules/store.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<store>.scripts.c0._c_anonymous_17(<store>/scripts/server.js:266)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.<store>.scripts.c0.call(<store>/scripts/server.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.c1._c_anonymous_69(/store/modules/store.js:1140)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.modules.c1.call(/store/modules/store.js)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.callN(OptRuntime.java:52)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.extensions.assets.mobileapp.pages.c1._c_script_0(/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag:4)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.extensions.assets.mobileapp.pages.c1.call(/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.store.extensions.assets.mobileapp.pages.c1.exec(/store/extensions/assets/mobileapp/pages/asset.jag)
    at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:567)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.appmgt.mobile.store.Devices.getDevicesList(Devices.java:101)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
    ... 83 more
```

I don't relly understand what's happen, does anyone got an idea ?

Comment: What's the EMM version you are using? Did you get this error when viewing  the app details page is it?

Comment: Sorry I missed some infos : I'm using WSO2 EMM 2.0.1.
When I'm logged on https://[domain]:9443/store I can see the app I've just added, when I click on the icon of the app, I got the error 500.

Comment: I could see a couple of similar issues were reported. Could you try the latest version? Probably this might have been fixed.

Comment: I've got the last version as I can see here -> http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-mobility-manager/

The other versions seems to be BETA one's and needs to setup again all the server ....

Comment: You can find the latest released version here https://github.com/wso2/product-emm/releases/tag/v2.1.1